# multiple if-else statement confusion perl

Tags: perl

I'm having a problem with my if-else statement. Even if the `$key` I'm using matches the text in my `if` statement, the `else` statement I have at the bottom is also evaluated, so I'm getting multiple values for each `$key`, which is a problem. What am I doing wrong here?

```
my $key = $line[0];
if ($key eq 'this_setting') {
    my $counter1 = $counter + 1;
    my $counter2 = $counter + 2;
    $value = join(' ', @line[$counter1..$counter2]);                        
    $my_setting_hash{$key} = $value;
}
if ($key eq 'some_setting_abc') {
    my $counter1 = $counter + 1;
    my $counter2 = $counter + 2;
    $value = join(' ', @line[$counter1..$counter2]);
    $my_setting_hash{$key} = $value;
}
if ($key eq 'another_setting_123') {
    my $counter1 = $counter + 1;
    my $counter3 = $counter + 3;
    $value = join(' ', @line[$counter1..$counter3]);
    $my_setting_hash{$key} = $value;
}       
else {
    my $counter1 = $counter + 1;
    $value = $line[$counter1];
    $my_setting_hash{$key} = $value;
}
```

Why is this `else` statement not bypassed if one of my `if` statements is evaluated?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to chain them together with [`elsif`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Compound-Statements):

```
my $key = $line[0];
if ($key eq 'this_setting') {
    my $counter1 = $counter + 1;
    my $counter2 = $counter + 2;
    $value = join(' ', @line[$counter1..$counter2]);                        
    $my_setting_hash{$key} = $value;
}
elsif ($key eq 'some_setting_abc') {
    my $counter1 = $counter + 1;
    my $counter2 = $counter + 2;
    $value = join(' ', @line[$counter1..$counter2]);
    $my_setting_hash{$key} = $value;
}
elsif ($key eq 'another_setting_123') {
    my $counter1 = $counter + 1;
    my $counter3 = $counter + 3;
    $value = join(' ', @line[$counter1..$counter3]);
    $my_setting_hash{$key} = $value;
}       
else {
    my $counter1 = $counter + 1;
    $value = $line[$counter1];
    $my_setting_hash{$key} = $value;
}
```

Otherwise, the first two `if` statements are independent of the third `if`/`else` statement.

Comment: I think you mean `elsif`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - Yeah, just corrected that. I actually had it right, then my brain hiccupped and I "corrected" it to `elseif`. Now it's back again.

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful and concise.

Answer (score 6):

As has already been pointed out, you need the keyword [elsif](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/elsif.html)

However, another solution is to put your special rules for each key into a hash and so that you can share code:

```
my %key_length = (
    this_setting        => 1,
    some_setting_abc    => 1,
    another_setting_123 => 2,
);

my $key = $line[0];

my $index_low = $counter + 1;
my $index_high = $index_low + ($key_length{$key} // 0);

$my_setting_hash{$key} = join ' ', @line[ $index_low .. $index_high ];
```

Answer (score 4):

Let's say `$key`'s value is `'some_setting_abc'`. Your first `if` does not apply, but the second `if` does. The third `if` does not apply either but that one has an `else` therefore that is executed. As [@TedHopp pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31713313/100754), you need a single `if` with chained `elsif`s and a final `else` instead.

However, I want to point out that there is a lot of duplication in your code. Life is simpler when you write code a bit more succinctly:

```
my $key = $line[0];
my $index = $counter + 1;

if (($key eq 'this_setting') or ($key eq 'some_setting_abc')) {
    $my_setting_hash{$key} = join ' ', @line[$index .. ($index + 1)];
}
elsif ($key eq 'another_setting_123') {
    $my_setting_hash{$key} = join ' ', @line[$index .. ($index + 2)];
}       
else {
    $my_setting_hash{$key} = $line[$index];
}
```